# Hyper V to Virtual PC

Tags: virtual-pc, hyper-v

I am currently using Windows Server 2008 Standard and have several Hyper V machines. These are development VM's and I want to now switch back Vista x64 because I am missing Aero.

I know Windows Server 2008 can have aero but the host performance is very very bad when I run VM in Hyper V.

I want to export my Hyper V machines so that I can use it in Virtual PC. Anyone know an easy way?

Comment: You're missing Aero? Check out http://win2008workstation.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VPC to Hyper-V is one way.

Comment: Says who? Please provide a reference for this statement.

Answer (score 4):

If you have built them as Hyper-V machines, I don't think you can go back.  There are serious differences in the HAL for Virtual PC and Hyper-V.  You can move a VPC to Hyper-V permanantly by removing the VPC add-ins ans adding the Hyper-V integration drivers/services and re-detecting the hardware.

A VPC can run in Hyper-V just fine, don't add the machine drivers for Hyper-V and you can go back to VPC with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hyper-V is designed to be used on the server, obviously. Whereas VirtualPC is designed for the end user. Hyper-V will give you more control, and the ability to create and restore snapshots. However, it does not have a direct console interface to the VM, you would use a browser to access the console. I would go Hyper-V, but it really depends on what you're using your VMs for. Luckily, they share the same format for virtual disks, so you can try it out with your existing VMs.

Answer (score 0):

You should review Windows 2008 R2 SP1 upgrade with RemoteFX, it comes with a new video driver for VM's that allow 3D, extended desktops and more. It will help resolve some of the issues you are seeing today.

Both the Host server and VM need to be running SP1 of Windows 2008 R2.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/virtualization/archive/2010/03/18/explaining-microsoft-remotefx.aspx